# Python Import Visible Globally But Not Within Class

Tags: python, class, reference, import, module

I am trying to import a python module to another (both in the same directory).
However it is only visible globally and not within the class definition as this screenshot shows:
[image]

What could be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: In the future, it's really helpful to post the source and the error message as text, even if you also have a nice screenshot from your IDE. (For one thing, the search index won't be able to parse your screenshot.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have used `terrain` as a local variable later in the `__init__` methods code.  Use a different variable name.